# Googlemaps API loads slow with many markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, page-load-time

Im trying to load around 600 googlemap markers on page load using the function addMarker.

The page takes a lot of time to load.

Is there anything I can do to make it load faster while keep using the addMarker function?

Thanks.

```js
var map
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.9531719,14.3712201);
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markers = {};
 
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) 
{
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomout, "click", function() {
  
    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if(currentZoomLevel != 0)
    {
   map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);
    }     
 });
 
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomin, "click", function() {
  
    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if(currentZoomLevel != 21)
    {
   map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);
    }
 });
}

function initialize() 
{
  var googleMapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.9531719,14.3712201),
 zoom: 11,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 zoomControl: false,
 streetViewControl: false,
 panControl: false,
 draggable: true
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), googleMapOptions);
  
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
    addMarker(latitude,longitude,id,'Title','url');
   }); 
  
  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
}

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: ""
 });

 function addMarker(lat,long,id,desc,url) 
 { 
 var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/images/pips/"+id+".png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(28,38));
 
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  title: desc,
  position: myLatlng,
  icon: myIcon,      
  id: id
 });
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent('<a href="' + url + '">' + desc + '</a>');
  infowindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
  infowindow.open(map, marker); 
 });
 
 markers[id] = marker;

 markerBounds.extend(myLatlng);
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
 });
 } 
 
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Answer (score -3):

You can use [clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers), it joins neighbor markers into one, and expand only on zoom

You can do clustering in client side, as well as server side, depending the amount of markers...

I would suggest to use server clustering if amount is more than 4000, otherwise client should look fine